# Suppose $\int\limits_0^1 f(xt)dt =0$ $\forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$, show that $f$ is identically 0.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\int\limits_0^1 f(xt)dt =0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $f(x)=0, \ \forall \  x\in \mathbb{R}$?

---

Here is my proof:

Consider the integral $\int\limits_0^1 f(xt)dt=0$.

Introduce the change of variable $xt=u$, we get the following integral

$\frac{1}{x}\int\limits_0^x f(u)du=0$

This implies that $\int\limits_0^x f(u)du=0$. Differentiating we get $f(x)=0 \ \forall \ x$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It is correct. Congrats!

Comment: Also asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257902/42969. Your proof is the same as in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/257919/42969

Comment: minor remark, you should handle the case $f(0)$ separately.